# Read pyodbc query results into variables

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

**Context:** I'm trying to query data from SQL Server via Pyodbc & use looping logic to read the results into the variables in the query block below.

**Question(s):** Can someone please help me modify the code block below so that it properly populates the variables via the looping logic? I suspect because I'm using the **fetchall()** method on the query cursor that each result row transforms into a tuple within a list -- which then seems to make the looping logic below it useless. Can someone please suggest an alternative solution?

```
from constantcontact import ConstantContact
from constantcontact import Contact
import requests
import json
import pyodbc

username = 'REDACTED'
password = 'REDACTED'

sample_contact_connection = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};""Server=PC;""Database=leadgen_sandbox;""Username="+username+";""Password="+password+";""Trusted_Connection=yes;")
sample_contact_cursor = sample_contact_connection.cursor()

sample_contact_query = "SELECT first_name,last_name,title,company_name,email_address FROM leadgen_sandbox.dbo.sample_contacts"
sample_contact_connection.autocommit = True
sample_contact_cursor.execute(sample_contact_query)
print(sample_contact_cursor.fetchall())

constantcontact = ConstantContact('REDACTED','REDACTED')
list_id = '1816761971'

for [first_name, last_name, title, company_name, email_address] in sample_contact_cursor.fetchall():
  new_contact = Contact()
  new_contact.set_first_name(''+first_name+'')
  new_contact.set_last_name(''+last_name+'')
  new_contact.set_job_title(''+title+'')
  new_contact.set_company_name(''+company_name+'')
  new_contact.add_list_id(''+list_id+'')
  new_contact.set_email_address(''+email_address+'')
  response = constantcontact.post_contacts(new_contact)
  response_text = json.dumps(response, indent = 4, sort_keys = True)
  print(response_text)
  sample_contact_connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you called sample_contact_cursor.fetchall() , you already exhausted the contents of the cursor. So, it's content would no longer be available for the loop. **Removing the print before the loop would fix this**. Also, the .fetchall() is redundant in the loop as each row would be read in the for loop one by one anyways. You could write this way as well:

```
for [first_name, last_name, title, company_name, email_address] in sample_contact_cursor:
  new_contact = Contact()
  new_contact.set_first_name(''+first_name+'')
  new_contact.set_last_name(''+last_name+'')
  #Write your remaining code
```

If you do need to first print the cursor, and then run the loop, you have to execute the cursor once agin before the loop like this:

```
sample_contact_cursor.execute(sample_contact_query)
print(sample_contact_cursor.fetchall())

constantcontact = ConstantContact('REDACTED','REDACTED')
list_id = '1816761971'

sample_contact_cursor.execute(sample_contact_query)

for [first_name, last_name, title, company_name, email_address] in sample_contact_cursor:
  new_contact = Contact()
  new_contact.set_first_name(''+first_name+'')
  new_contact.set_last_name(''+last_name+'')
  #Write your remaining code
```